# Export data from GBQ into CSV with specific encoding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Im using GBQ, I want to export the results of a query into CSV file.
The data is larger than 20M lines so Im using this option :

[image]

In my query results I have some text in french, that is being saved in bad encoding to CSV.
Is there a way to define the encoding on Saving step in GBQ ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is such possibility.. But it seems weird to me: BQ exports in UTF-8 which should be fine for French (or any language actually).. isn't it rather an issue with the way your text is imported inside BQ ? Are your french characters displaying properly when you query  them ?

Comment: @Cylldby yes they are displayed well in GBQ results. But once seen in CSV, they are in bad encoding.

Comment: What program do you use to open the resulting CSV ? Is it ... Excel ? 0_0

Comment: @Cylldby once I export it in CSV, I exploit the CSV in R. On import level, whatever encoding I define, the french characters are not well encoded. So I realized its at the level of export.

Comment: This is not normal. BigQuery exports to UTF-8 which should not cause any issue with French character (I could not reproduce your issue with french characters exported to Drive csv, everything works fine). There could be issues with Excel and BOM related problems.

Comment: Is there any treatment between export from BQ and import in R?

Comment: Can you try both of the following ?

Comment: df <- read.csv("yourcsv.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

Comment: df <- read.csv("yourcsv.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write simple Python script (or another language that made you feel comfortable) to query and save the result by using Python code. So you can use any encoding you want to save your result to CSV file.

Comment: I ended up exporting the data from GBQ with python. Thank you.